# MySQL count records by months on timestampt

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, timestamp

I have a MySQL table like this

```
Transaction(transaction_id, seller_id, sale_date)
```

where `sale_date` is a timestamp.

I would like find out the number of sales each seller has made **in each month of the last three months**. I composed my query like this:

```
SELECT seller_id, COUNT(*) as num_of_sales
FROM Transaction
WHERE sale_date > '2014-11-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY seller_id, MONTH(sale_date)
```

and I am certain that the result is invalid since I got back:

```
seller_id  num_of_sales
2          4829 
5          148
```

and there is no such seller with id 5 in my seller table. Could anyone point me to the right direction, please? Thank you!

Comment: Based on your query and the results, there would appear to be a seller with an id that looks like "5".  I do note that you are grouping by month but not including that in the `select`.  That seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working query that I managed to come up with, hope it is useful for someone:

```
SELECT 
  MONTHNAME(sale_date) as d_month,
  seller_id,
  COUNT(*) as num_of_sales      
FROM Transaction
GROUP BY seller_id, d_month 
ORDER seller_id, MONTH(sale_date) asc
```